# Cant center my text with 'text-center'

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I centered my text vertically, Now i need to center it horizontaly to.
Did i miss something or its not possible to do `text-center` when i have `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="bild text-center">
    <h2 class="vit text-center">Mobiltelefoner & Surfplattor</h2>
    <img src="https://www.zong.com.pk/images/uploads/misc/4.internationalcalls_desktop-Banner.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.bild {
  width: 100%;
  background: url('https://www.zong.com.pk/images/uploads/misc/4.internationalcalls_desktop-Banner.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size:100% auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;   
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/1k8s3Rw322

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be your expectation.

```
<div align="center">
    <p>This is going to be aligned center</p>
    <p>This is also</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this kinda solves it, but it messes up my img src.